# Simply creating a toolbar in Ext JS

Tags: class, extjs, toolbar

So I have a panel with a top and bottom toolbar that is created within the dockedItems config:

```
dockedItems: [
    Ext.create('AM.view.TopToolbar',{}), //  //This line alone breaks the app
    { //Toolbars
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [
            { text: 'About', itemId: 'about' },
            '-',
            { text: 'Legal', itemId: 'legal' },
            ...
```

The code works fine in FF, but breaks in IE9. I think it has to do with the syntax of my create statement, but I cannot find a solution on the forums.

Here's my TopToolbar class:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.TopToolbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    alias: 'widget.toptoolbar',
    defaults: { arrowCls: '' }, //Removing black arrow from toolbar items
    items: [
        { text : 'Tools', 
            menu : {
                items: [
                //rest of my toolbar items and menus
```

All file structures are correct and working.

Namespace is 'AM'

Application breaks in Internet Explorer-have not tried in Chrome or Safari

I get this Error

```
: SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
ext-all.js, line 38 character 51878
```

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Post all relevant code please

Comment: Edited to include my toolbar class

Comment: What is the (probably vague) error you get in IE?

Comment: Error: SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
ext-all.js, line 38 character 51878

Comment: Instead of ext-all.js try using ext-all-debug.js it should give you a better idea of whats going wrong (by that I mean the line# and character# will point you at some readable extjs code)

Comment: I checked out that and debug-w-comments.js and they mentioned the  Ext.syncRequire(name), I'll tread into it

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `Ext.create` instead of the top toolbar's `xtype`? I'm not sure you can even do that.

Comment: I want to instantiate my defined TopToolbar class, how could that be done using xtype?